# How to increase font size dynamically in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am creating Silver light Application.

My problem is that how to increase font size when i re-size Browser.
Ex. Suppose my browser size is 1024 X 768 And all the control's having Font size is 11px.

When i Increase my screen resolution to 1366 X 768 then font size is also increased.

How to possible it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You  use RenderTransform and ScaleTransform for Scale your font.

you can use this link

[Link](http://10rem.net/blog/2008/07/04/how-to-resize-a-silverlight-2-app-and-keep-the-same-aspect-ratio)